# Can't find graphic card in Device Manager but display works

Tags: windows-xp, gpu

I have an old computer that I want to fix but it acts strange. I have a monitor connected to the GPU and it displays everything correctly (just slow). It's typical behavior for missing drivers. However the problem is there's no graphic card or anything that would even look similar in the Device Manager.

Does anyone have any idea how to make it visible once again? I've already tried to remove it and put it back again but no luck. GPU is Gigabyte GV-R925128D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been ages since I've done hardware troubleshooting in Windows, but I think the thing to do is to go into safe mode, then pull up the device manager again.  If I recall, this will show all installed drivers--even for devices that are not currently connected to the system.  I suggest uninstalling all graphics drivers you see at this stage.  Then reboot again.  Hopefully this will trigger a re-detection of your video hardware when you reboot.

Comment: It's been ages since I've been playing with hardware troubleshooting as well :-) Especially on this very old equipment. I'll try your advice and let you know.

Comment: It wasn't visible in safe mode but i deleted some of Via PCI to AGP and similar entries (basically everything with AGP in name) from Non Plug And Play Devices and it found Radeon 9200 on next boot.